# ReactJs - access nested array in JSON response

Tags: javascript, reactjs

JSON Response:

```css
Bars: [
{
id: "7",
name: "The Trestle Inn",
address: "339 N 11th St",
city: "Philadelphia",
state: "PA",
category: "Dive Bar",
checkIn: [
{
wait: "0.1",
vibe: "0.35",
crowd: "0.5"
}
],
eventname: "0"
},
{
id: "9",
name: "McGillin's Olde Ale House",
address: "1310 Drury Street",
city: "Philadelphia",
state: "PA",
category: "Pub",
checkIn: [
{
wait: "0.1",
vibe: "0.4",
crowd: "0.2"
}
],
eventname: "0"
},
```

I am using ReactJs, and attempting to iterate through "Bars", pulling data. I can successfully access the first-tier response, such as Name and Address, but I am failing to process the sub-array "checkIn", where I want to pull the values for 'vibe', 'wait', and 'crowd'.

```js
var WebApp = React.createClass({
 componentDidMount: function(){
  this.loadFavoritesData();
 },

 render: function(){
  return(
      <div>
       <Favorites favoritesData={this.state.favoritesData} />
       <Newsfeed />
      </div>
   )
 }
});

var Favorites = React.createClass({
 render: function(){
  //console.log(this.props.favoritesData);

  var favoriteNodes = this.props.favoritesData.map(function(favorite, index){

   var checkInNodes = favorite.checkIn.map(function(data){
    //console.log(data.vibe);
    return {data}
   });

   console.log(checkInNodes.vibe);
   
   return(
      <Favorite
      name={favorite.name}
      address={favorite.address}
      key={index}
      vibe={checkInNodes.vibe}
      />

    )
  });

  return(
     <div>
       <h2 className="page-header">Favorite Bars</h2>
       {favoriteNodes}
     </div>
   )
 }
});

var Favorite = React.createClass({
 render: function(){
  return(
    <div className="favoriteItem">
     <h4>{this.props.name}</h4>
     <p>{this.props.address}</p>
     <p>Vibe: {this.props.vibe}</p>
    </div>
   )
 }
});
```

I had initially figured I could access it within the first map function within the Favorites component, but when attempting something like the following, I get an undefined result for favorite.checkIn.vibe although if I console.log(favorite.checkIn) I will return the object, which again, I can't seem to dive into

```js
var Favorites = React.createClass({
 render: function(){
  var favoriteNodes = this.props.favoritesData.map(function(favorite, index){
   console.log(favorite.checkIn.vibe);
   return(
      <Favorite
      name={favorite.name}
      address={favorite.address}
      key={index}
      vibe={favorite.checkIn.vibe}
      />

    )
  });
```

Answer (score 0):

## Short Answer

I think you want to do this:

`Bars[0].checkIn[0].wait`

The second index seems to be missing from your code above.

## Longer Answer

If you only ever have one object in the checkIn array, you might want to consider taking them out of the array so the object looks like this:

```
{
    id: "9",
    name: "McGillin's Olde Ale House",
    address: "1310 Drury Street",
    city: "Philadelphia",
    state: "PA",
    category: "Pub",
    checkInWait: "0.1",
    checkInVibe: "0.4",
    checkInCrowd: "0.2",
    eventname: "0"
}
```

and then the code would be much cleaner. If you can't change the data, try this:

```
for (var i = 0; i < Bars.length; i++) {
  // set the variables above the checkIn
  for (var j = 0; j < Bars[i].checkIn.length; j++) {
    // set Bars[i].checkIn[j].wait
    // set Bars[i].checkIn[j].vibe
    // set Bars[i].checkIn[j].crowd
  }
  // set the eventname variable
}
```

Comment: By the way, your code is really hard to read with all the tabs. You can go into your editor to exchange tabs for spaces and set them to 2 or 4 spaces tops. Alternatively, you can open vim on a Mac or Linux machine: ```vim [filename]``` then ```:%s/TAB/TWO_SPACES/g``` (except press tab and hit the spacebar twice) then ```:wq``` and it will exchange all of the tabs for spaces

Comment: Thanks for the answer, and also the tip! I can't change the source data, so I'll look into the second option you provided and see what I can do